# Поиск ключевых слов в тексте

Tags: php

```
$text = '....';
$key = 'слово,слово,слово';

if (.....) {
  //true
} else {
  //false
}
```

Как выполнить поиск по тексту и если в тексте есть хоть одно ключевое слово, то выполнить условие?

Comment: `if ( strpos($text, $key) === false ) { //не найдено } else { //нашли  }`

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '....';
$search = 'слово,слово,слово';

if (false !== strpos($text, $search)) {
  //true
} else {
  //false
}
```